# Zoom to layer bounds on popup close in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, extents, popup, zoom

I have a GeoJSON data layer in a small Leaflet project and initially I zoom to its bounds.

```
map.fitBounds(dataLayer.getBounds());
```

I bind popups to each feature and zoom to the clicked feature when the popup is being opened:

```
function onEachPoint(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(
       '<h2>' + feature.properties.name + '</h2>' +
       '<p><!-- more content here --></p>'
    );
    layer.on({
        click: (e) => {
            map.setView(e.latlng, 16, {'animate': true});
        } 
    })
};
```

What is the best way to zoom back to the layer bounds when the popup is being closed?

I found [this SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52447405), but unfortunately I wasn't able so far to combine it with my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to achieve you can use the [popup-close](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layer-popupclose) event. Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cthnwps4/).

```js
// center of the map
const center = [48, 15];

// Create the map
const map = L.map('map').setView(center, 7);

// Set up the OSM layer
L.tileLayer(
    'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18
    }
).addTo(map);

// Add Geojson
const dataLayer = L.geoJSON(data)
    .bindPopup(function(layer) {
        return '<h2>' + layer.feature.properties.name + '</h2>';
    })
    .on({
        click: (e) => {
            map.setView(e.latlng, 16, {
                'animate': true
            });
        }
    })
    .on({
        popupclose: (e) => {
            map.fitBounds(dataLayer.getBounds());
        }
    })
    .addTo(map);

// Zoom to dataLayer
map.fitBounds(dataLayer.getBounds());
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect!